# Understanding of xpath with '.' as an attribute

Tags: xpath

For few of Stackoverflow question/answers, I find xpath like `//div[.='hello']` Can someone please explain what exactly role of `.` in the expression and when to use it?

Comment: It's a current node reference, not necessarily an attribute. Explicit attribute reference begins with `@`, for example `//div[@class='container']` selects those `div` elements which have a `class` attribute and the attribute has value `'container'` and it is equivalent to (though shorter than) `//div[./@class='container']`.

Comment: But what could be in `hello` in expression `//div[.='hello']`. Attribute value for current node's any of the attribute? I tried but it's not like that.

Comment: It is not called an attribute, but a predicate.

Comment: A dot expression gets compared to 'hello', which is a string constant. So the current node, represented by a dot, is converted to a so-called 'string-value' and that value becomes a string to comparision. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value for a standard's note on converting an XML node to a string-value and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions for a standard function to do such conversion explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
//div[. = 'hello']
```

Will find all div elements whose string value is "hello". The string value of an element is defined to be the concatenation of all that element's descendant text nodes, so all the following elements would match:

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>hel<i>lo</i></div>
<div>h<i>el</i>lo</div>
```

`text()` is different - it is a location path step that extracts the set of all text node children of the current context node. So

```
//div[text() = 'hello']
```

finds div elements that have at least one text node child whose value is "hello" (remember `=` on a node set has an implicit existential quantifier) - this would match the first example above but not the second or third, and would also match things like

```
<div>foo bar baz<br/>hello</div>
```

because *one* of the text node children is "hello".

It gets even hairier if you want to apply a function to the value returned by the path expression, for example consider

```
<div>
  <!-- some comment -->
  hello
</div>
```

The expression `//div[contains(., 'hello')]` will find this element, but `//div[contains(text(), 'hello')]` will not! The div in this example has two text node children (one containing the newline and spaces before the comment, the other containing "hello" with its surrounding whitespace), so XPath 2.0 will raise a type error as you've given it a sequence of two items where it expected a single string. But XPath 1.0 will accept the expression, and convert the two-node set to a string by silently ignoring all but the *first* node in the set and thus fail to match.

I very rarely need to use `text()` in a stylesheet, unless I'm writing a template that cares about processing individual text nodes one by one - in predicates it's almost always `.` rather than `text()` that you really mean.

Comment: Very good canonical answer. This should be part of the Stack Overflow XPath FAQ :)

Answer (score 0):

I could find it, it looks for matching element with the text in the node.

For HTML snippet:

```
<a ui-sref="main.home" href="#/home" class="">Home</a>
```

If I use following xpath, it searches an element with text `Home`

```
//a[.='Home']
```

But it looks same as `//a[text()='Home']`

If someone knows how `//a[.='Home']` differs/is better than `//a[text()='Home']` Please do explain.

Comment: according to [this](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xpath-punctuation-part-1), `dot` is called the `context item expression`, it is similar to `this` in javascript.

Comment: `text()` will give you all text nodes. For example //a/text() would return all the text nodes. You can also use `[2]` with it

Answer (score -1):

1) If the XPATH contains

`./` equivalent to current node.
Eg:`//tbody[@id='tableID']/tr[./td[3][text()='Sample']]` ---- under `tbody` with ID as 'tableID', `tr`having `td` with text as `Sample`

2) `//div[.='hello']` equivalent to `//div[text()='hello']`
Eg: `//button[contains(.,'Apply changes')]` ---- Button with text contains "Apply changes"

Comment: `. =` and `text() =` are _not_ equivalent.